# FFmpeg: UDP statistics

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, udp, video-streaming, rtsp

I'm using `FFmpeg` in my iOS application to read an RTSP (over UDP) stream. VLC offers some media information -> statistics about the stream that is being played. The number of Video Frames lost is what I'm interested in.

My question: is there a way to get these statistics (frames lost) with FFmpeg while reading from an UDP stream?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the VLC source to see how it gets that information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RTCP is used to collect statistics. Check if ffmpeg libs provide some API to access RTCP information

Comment: Yes, the RTCP information is what I need to access. The problem is that I cannot find how (using FFmpeg). In absence of another answer, I'll choose this one. Thanks.

Comment: @MihaiGhete According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20265546/reading-rtcp-packets-from-an-ip-camera-using-ffmpeg) you can get RTPDemuxContext:
`
RTSPState* rtsp_state = (RTSPState*) context->priv_data;
RTSPStream* rtsp_stream = rtsp_state->rtsp_streams[0];
RTPDemuxContext* rtp_demux_context = (RTPDemuxContext*) rtsp_stream->transport_priv;
`
which can give you [RTCP info](http://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.0/structRTPDemuxContext.html)