# Extracting a timestamp from a RTCP Packet Sender Report

Tags: webrtc, ntp, rtcp

I'm using tcpdump in the manner described here http://www.erg.abdn.ac.uk/multicast/tools_notes/tcpdump.html#rtp to extract RTCP packets between my browser and a media server I have running.

Some example data:

```
192.168.56.1.55281 > 192.168.56.103.56858:  sr 2060503618 @4039366103.08 2985649056 3759504059p 947804803b type-0xfa 160544
192.168.56.1.55281 > 192.168.56.103.56858:  sr 2060503618 @4086113093.65 724273245 4090890645p 3217937232b type-0x6e 28300
192.168.56.1.55281 > 192.168.56.103.56858:  sr 2060503618 @2251420711.18 185215175 650796127p 3621147513b type-0x66 120348
```

From what I understand the number after the @ symbol is a NTP Reference timestamp, and the number following that is the media timestamp reference, however when I convert these to dates they seem random, and neither timestamp is ever close to the actual time.

From looking around it seems like the following are equally possible:

a) I'm completely missing something.

b) I'm seeing encrypted data.

c) I'm seeing the result of buggy code.

This question: [Reading RTCP packets from an IP camera using FFMPEG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20265546/reading-rtcp-packets-from-an-ip-camera-using-ffmpeg) looks very much related, except it dealt with RTSP, not RTP.

Answer (score 0):

b) was correct. The data is encrypted with WebRTC.